# comment out json before send to client

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson

in spring 3 controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee/{id}", RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable long empID) {
    Employee employee = employeeService.getByID(empID);
    return employee;
}
```

which file should i modify, so that the json would return like below

instead of returning `"['foo', 'bar']"`

return this  `"/*['foo', 'bar']*/"`  (with comment)  ?

Comment: what's the use-case for this?

Comment: @skaffman, u mean what the reason of doing this? go here http://tinyurl.com/mq96sh, see title 'Protecting Your Single-Site Application'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underneath the covers, Spring MVC delegates to a `HttpMessageConverter` to perform the serialization. In this case, Spring MVC invokes a `MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter` built on the **Jackson JSON processor**. This implementation is enabled automatically when you use the **mvc:annotation-driven** configuration element with **Jackson present in your classpath.**

So, you can provide your own `HttpMessageConverter`  implementation by overriding

```
protected void writeInternal(Object o,
                         HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
                  throws IOException,
                         HttpMessageNotWritableException
```

method of **MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter**, which could server the purpose.

Comment: is it possible to use spring interceptor postHandle to do this? if yes, what should i put for the postHandle method? how to get the raw json from this method?

Comment: @cometta I don't think you will be able to modify the content that has already been flushed/committed, so using only postHandle will not be the right solution. You will require to use a preHandle too.

Answer (score 1):

Quick note regarding comments: comments are not (alas!) part of JSON specification, so using them means using non-standard JSON.

For what it's worth, it is possible to make some JSON parsers (including Jackson) handle comments (for Jackson, see http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeaturesParser); as well as write them (need to use 'JsonGenerator.writeRaw("/*...*/")').

But maybe Spring has a way to decorate response, as that would probably be simpler to implement.